# Can a legendary creature use a Legendary Resistance to pass a Grapple Check?

Tags: dnd-5e

If a a legendary creature is grappled by a player character, can they choose to escape? it isn't technically a Saving Throw, but a skill check.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have answered your own question.

Legendary Resistance allows the monster to succeed on a Saving Throw only.
 Escaping a grapple is a skill/ability check.
Therefore Legendary Resistance is not applicable to escaping a grapple.